# 6F00 error during AuthenticateServer step of downloading profile on esim

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error, euiccmanager

I am making a LPA application for mobile esim using SE service to communicate with EUICC on a rooted pixel device on AOSP OS following SGP .22-2.3 specs, but while trying to download the profile on the esim in AuthenticateServer step I am getting 6F00 error code which translates to "No precise diagnosis".
Till InitiateAuthentication step everything is working fine. I don't know whats going wrong.

For profile download I am using Google's SAIP test profiles. I have already checked the ctxParam values and they are correct as per the device. I am attaching the logs of the process for reference.

```
2023-10-17 13:46:07.200 4813-4834/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: addProfile: activationCode = LPA:1$prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog$052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL, smdsAddress = null, type = 0, inputSupported = true
2023-10-17 13:46:07.200 4813-4834/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: checkRequestAllowed: requestType = 4, myUID = 10040, callingUID = 10106
2023-10-17 13:46:07.206 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: openChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:07.206 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: permissionState = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:07.206 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: Pref: selectedReader: 
2023-10-17 13:46:07.207 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: selectedReader: eSE1
2023-10-17 13:46:07.208 4813-5764/  I/SEService: true
2023-10-17 13:46:07.245 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: ISDR response: 6F1F8410A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100A5049F6501FFE00582030202009000
2023-10-17 13:46:07.246 4813-5764/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: intermediateProgress: progress = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:07.246 4813-5764/  D/ActivationCode: getParsedActivationCode: activationCode = LPA:1$prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog$052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL, mACFormat = 1, mSMDPAddress = prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog, mACToken = 052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL, mSMDPid = null, mConfirmationFlag = false
2023-10-17 13:46:07.246 4813-5764/  D/ActivationCode: getParsedActivationCode: activationCode = LPA:1$prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog$052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL, mACFormat = 1, mSMDPAddress = prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog, mACToken = 052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL, mSMDPid = null, mConfirmationFlag = false
2023-10-17 13:46:07.247 4813-5764/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: ES10c GetProfilesInfo
2023-10-17 13:46:07.247 4813-5764/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: PROFILE_LIST_RETRY 0
2023-10-17 13:46:07.249 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 91, p2: 00, p3: 0D, data: BF2D0A5C085A4F9F709295B799
2023-10-17 13:46:07.250 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu: 80E291000DBF2D0A5C085A4F9F709295B799
2023-10-17 13:46:07.261 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: BF2D02A0009000
2023-10-17 13:46:07.264 4813-5764/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: PROFILE_LIST_RESPONSE 0
2023-10-17 13:46:07.264 4813-5764/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: intermediateProgress: progress = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:07.264 4813-5764/  D/LpaWorker: AddProfile with Activation Code: smdpAddress - prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog, matchingId - 052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL, smdpOid - null, confirmationCodeRequired - false
2023-10-17 13:46:07.264 4813-5764/  D/LPD: ES10b GetEUICCInfo
2023-10-17 13:46:07.267 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 91, p2: 00, p3: 03, data: BF2000
2023-10-17 13:46:07.267 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu: 80E2910003BF2000
2023-10-17 13:46:07.363 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: BF20618203020200A92C041481370F5125D0B1D408D4C3B232E6D25E795BEBFB0414B60F0B897FD630B88CFED6161F8EA808C5382AC3AA2C041481370F5125D0B1D408D4C3B232E6D25E795BEBFB0414B60F0B897FD630B88CFED6161F8EA808C5382AC39000
2023-10-17 13:46:07.364 4813-5764/  D/GetEUICCInfoResponse: Don't ignore check of eUICC certificate for verification
2023-10-17 13:46:07.364 4813-5764/  D/GetEUICCInfoResponse: Don't ignore check of eUICC certificate for signing
2023-10-17 13:46:07.370 4813-5764/  D/LPD: ES10b GetEUICCChallenge
2023-10-17 13:46:07.371 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 91, p2: 00, p3: 03, data: BF2E00
2023-10-17 13:46:07.372 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu: 80E2910003BF2E00
2023-10-17 13:46:07.392 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: BF2E128010BEC465E972B29CD547EB2077F122E16A9000
2023-10-17 13:46:07.399 4813-5764/  D/LPD: ES9+ InitiateAuthentication
2023-10-17 13:46:07.401 4813-5764/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl:  > prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog/gsma/rsp2/es9plus/initiateAuthentication
    {"euiccChallenge":"vsRl6XKynNVH6yB38SLhag==","euiccInfo1":"vyBhggMCAgCpLAQUgTcPUSXQsdQI1MOyMubSXnlb6/sEFLYPC4l/1jC4jP7WFh+OqAjFOCrDqiwEFIE3D1El0LHUCNTDsjLm0l55W+v7BBS2DwuJf9YwuIz+1hYfjqgIxTgqww==","smdpAddress":"prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog"}
2023-10-17 13:46:07.700 4813-5764/  D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(72) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2023-10-17 13:46:09.138 4813-5764/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: response buffer: {"header":{"functionExecutionStatus":{"status":"Executed-Success"}},"transactionId":"38276E39BBF53DB1995BCF5204FFE9F1","serverSigned1":"ME+AEDgnbjm79T2xmVvPUgT/6fGBEL7EZelyspzVR+sgd/Ei4WqDF3Byb2Quc21kcC1wbHVzLnJzcC5nb29nhBDsDLtiTctqO0HrZ71xX/Vc","serverSignature1":"XzdAgWFiSsP4O2gVZ4qnmhHXx2tuhKeODhkHlemj/UHUsopbV1lS3qd7TEDFZ7/O30hGxxeurf30aMN+WoMl1mDNrQ\u003d\u003d","euiccCiPKIdToBeUsed":"BBS2DwuJf9YwuIz+1hYfjqgIxTgqww\u003d\u003d","serverCertificate":"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 size: 1024
2023-10-17 13:46:09.138 4813-5764/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: response buffer: UdIwQYMBaAFLYPC4l/1jC4jP7WFh+OqAjFOCrDMB0GA1UdDgQWBBThDxQ1WDQrvSKcSJ8bacAJLDQf2TAVBgNVHREEDjAMiAorBgEEAdZ5BgEDMBcGA1UdIAEB/wQNMAswCQYHZ4ESAQIBBDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIhAKf6KuLFCtWIo7HXEBvmK13jJWlyQl+a6JYCrTcegF9SAiBfnwauxju7TGmkvF3y5+jGWfCpz3MrwBrF+IhO3J992A\u003d\u003d"} size: 294
2023-10-17 13:46:09.139 4813-5764/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: response data size: 1318
2023-10-17 13:46:09.139 4813-5764/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: Server response: {"header":{"functionExecutionStatus":{"status":"Executed-Success"}},"transactionId":"38276E39BBF53DB1995BCF5204FFE9F1","serverSigned1":"ME+AEDgnbjm79T2xmVvPUgT/6fGBEL7EZelyspzVR+sgd/Ei4WqDF3Byb2Quc21kcC1wbHVzLnJzcC5nb29nhBDsDLtiTctqO0HrZ71xX/Vc","serverSignature1":"XzdAgWFiSsP4O2gVZ4qnmhHXx2tuhKeODhkHlemj/UHUsopbV1lS3qd7TEDFZ7/O30hGxxeurf30aMN+WoMl1mDNrQ\u003d\u003d","euiccCiPKIdToBeUsed":"BBS2DwuJf9YwuIz+1hYfjqgIxTgqww\u003d\u003d","serverCertificate":"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\u003d\u003d"}
2023-10-17 13:46:09.161 4813-5764/  D/LPD: serverAddress from AC: prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog, serverAddress from IAR: prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog
2023-10-17 13:46:09.170 4813-5764/  D/LPD: ES10b AuthenticateServer
2023-10-17 13:46:09.189 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 11, p2: 00, p3: FF, data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
2023-10-17 13:46:09.210 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: 9000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.211 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 11, p2: 01, p3: FF, data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
2023-10-17 13:46:09.225 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: 9000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.225 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 11, p2: 02, p3: FF, data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
2023-10-17 13:46:09.237 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: 9000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.239 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 91, p2: 03, p3: 6B, data: 9AE89602AD371E805F5202205F9F06AEC63BBB4C69A4BC5DF2E7E8C659F0A9CF732BC01AC5F8884EDC9F7DD8A03D8013303532582D554658532D435149592D504E474CA126800435293110A11E80030B000081030B00008203010000830303000084030C000085030B0000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.603 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: 6F00
2023-10-17 13:46:09.611 4813-5764/  D/LPD: AuthenticateServerRequest failed, error code: 256
2023-10-17 13:46:09.611 4813-5764/  E/LpaWorker: mutualAuthentication failed, error code: 256
2023-10-17 13:46:09.611 4813-5764/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: resetChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.612 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: resetChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.618 4813-5764/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: SE channel closed
2023-10-17 13:46:09.619 4813-5764/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: onRequestCompleted: status = 256
2023-10-17 13:46:09.651 4813-5762/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: getAvailableReaders
2023-10-17 13:46:09.651 4813-5762/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: checkRequestAllowed: requestType = 1, myUID = 10040, callingUID = 10106
2023-10-17 13:46:09.656 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: openChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.656 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: permissionState = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:09.656 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: Pref: selectedReader: 
2023-10-17 13:46:09.657 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: selectedReader: eSE1
2023-10-17 13:46:09.657 4813-5771/  I/SEService: true
2023-10-17 13:46:09.682 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: ISDR response: 6F1F8410A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100A5049F6501FFE00582030202009000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.682 4813-5771/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: intermediateProgress: progress = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:09.682 4813-5771/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: ES10c getAvailableReaders
2023-10-17 13:46:09.683 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: getAvailableReaders: [Telephony]
2023-10-17 13:46:09.683 4813-5771/  D/LpaWorker: getAvailableReaders:[Telephony]
2023-10-17 13:46:09.683 4813-5771/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: resetChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.683 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: resetChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.687 4813-5771/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: SE channel closed
2023-10-17 13:46:09.687 4813-5771/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: onReadersRetrieved: status = 0, readers = [Telephony]
2023-10-17 13:46:09.689 4813-5762/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: listProfiles
2023-10-17 13:46:09.693 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: openChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.693 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: permissionState = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:09.694 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: Pref: selectedReader: 
2023-10-17 13:46:09.694 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: selectedReader: eSE1
2023-10-17 13:46:09.695 4813-5772/  I/SEService: true
2023-10-17 13:46:09.734 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: ISDR response: 6F1F8410A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100A5049F6501FFE00582030202009000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.735 4813-5772/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: intermediateProgress: progress = 0
2023-10-17 13:46:09.736 4813-5772/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: ES10c GetProfilesInfo
2023-10-17 13:46:09.736 4813-5772/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: PROFILE_LIST_RETRY 0
2023-10-17 13:46:09.739 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel < cla: 80, ins: E2, p1: 91, p2: 00, p3: 18, data: BF2D15A0039501025C0E5A4F9F709295B79990919394B6B8
2023-10-17 13:46:09.740 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu: 80E2910018BF2D15A0039501025C0E5A4F9F709295B79990919394B6B8
2023-10-17 13:46:09.757 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: iccTransmitApdu result: BF2D02A0009000
2023-10-17 13:46:09.762 4813-5772/  D/LUI_2.4.0_api_2: PROFILE_LIST_RESPONSE 0
2023-10-17 13:46:09.763 4813-5772/  D/ServerInterfaceImpl: resetChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.763 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: resetChannel
2023-10-17 13:46:09.768 4813-5772/  D/EuiccInterfaceImpl SE service::: SE channel closed
2023-10-17 13:46:09.768 4813-5772/  D/LpaServiceImpl_2.4.0_api_2: onProfileListRetrieved: status = 0, profileList = []
```